# Not able to read file from server - on-premise CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

Trying to read file from server where CRM is installed. When I am reading the file from the server, plugin throws an error "Directory not found".

```
        Entity attachment = new Entity("activitymimeattachment");
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        byte[] byteData = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        stream.Close();
        // Encode the data using base64.
        string encodedData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        attachment["subject"] = "Attachment";
        attachment["filename"] = "emailstatement.pdf";
        //byte[] fileStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
        attachment["body"] = encodedData;
        attachment["mimetype"] = @"application\pdf";
        attachment["attachmentnumber"] = 1;
        attachment["objectid"] = new EntityReference("email", emailguid);
        attachment["objecttypecode"] = "email";
        service.Create(attachment);
```

Can anyone help me to read file from server using plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the error log says? Can you share?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171488/creating-dynamics-crm-plugin-to-execute-external-task/55172543#55172543

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820121/access-local-file-from-dynamics-365-and-local-resource-not-allowed/55821423#55821423

Comment: Error log :An Invalid plugin Exception occurred in the AddAttachment plug-in: 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Email\EmailStatement.pdf'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure your plugin is registered outside of the sandbox (in partial trust). Its an option in the plugin registration tool.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334752(v=crm.8))

> Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online & on-premises) support **the execution of
>   plug-ins and custom workflow activities in an isolated environment**. In
>   this isolated environment, **also known as a sandbox**, a plug-in or
>   custom activity can make use of the full power of the Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 SDK to access the organization web service. **Access to the
>   file system,** system event log, certain network protocols, registry,
>   and more **is prevented in the sandbox.**